# Fast bucket implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, graph-theory

In a graph class I need to handle nodes with integer values (1-1000 mostly). In every step I want to remove a node and all its neighbors from the graph. Also I want to always begin with the node of the minimal value. I thought long about how to do this in the fastest possible manner and decided to do the following:

- The graph is stored using adjancency lists
- There is a huge array `std::vector<Node*> bucket[1000]` to store the nodes by its value
- The index of the lowest nonempty bucket is always stored and kept track off
- I can find the node of minimal value very fast by picking a random element of that index or if the bucket is already empty increase the index
- Removing the selected node from the bucket can clearly done in O(1), the problem is that for removing the neighbors I need to search the bucket bucket[value of neighbor] first for all neighbor nodes, which is not really fast.

Is there a more efficient approach to this?

I thought of using something like `std::list<Node*> bucket[1000]`, and assign every node a pointer to its "list element", such that I can remove the node from the list in O(1). Is this possible with stl lists, clearly it can be done with a normal double linked list that I could implement by hand?

Comment: It feels weird to have STL containers in plain C arrays. And yes this remark is off-topic.

Comment: The relative speed of removing elements from vector and list is `k * O(n)` and `K * O(1)`. The values of `n`, `k`, and `K` are also important. If `n` is "small" on average, the vector can be very fast.

Comment: What's the output? An approximate minimum-weight dominating set?

Comment: @BoPersson I think the K is quite small for lists, you just have to adjust two pointers to "skip" a certain element in a linked list

Comment: @rapmusic that does not really matter here but yes you are right.

Comment: It matters because soft deletes are probably faster than hard deletes unless you need to access the intermediate graphs.

Comment: I actually already work with soft deletes because I work with pointers on the actual graph and just delete the pointers instead of actually accessing the nodes in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently did something similar to this for a priority queue implementation using buckets.

What I did was use a hash tables (unordered_map), that way, you don't need to store 1000 empty vectors and you still get O(1) random access (general case, not guaranteed). Now, if you only need to store/create this graph class one time, it probably doesn't matter. In my case I needed to create the priority queue tens/hundreds of time per second and using the hash map made a huge difference (due to the fact that I only created unordered_sets when I actually had an element of that priority, so no need to initialize 1000 empty hash sets). Hash sets and maps are new in C++11, but have been available in std::tr1 for a while now, or you could use the Boost libraries.

The only difference that I can see between your & my usecase, is that you also need to be able to remove neighboring nodes. I'm assuming every node contains a list of pointers to it's neighbors. If so, deletion of the neighbors should take `k * O(1)` with `k` the number of neighbors (again, O(1) in general, not guaranteed, worst case is O(n) in an unordered_map/set). You just go over every neighboring node, get its priority, that gives you the correct index into the hash map. Then you find the pointer in the hash set which the priority maps to, this search in general will be O(1) and removing the element is again O(1) in general.

All in all, I think you got a pretty good idea of what to do, but I believe that using hash maps/sets will speed up your code by quite a lot (depends on the exact usage of course). For me, the speed improvement of an implementation with `unordered_map<int, unordered_set>` versus `vector<set>` was around 50x.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising. I will try this and compare it with my current solution :-).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do. Node structure:

```
struct Node {
    std::vector<Node*>::const_iterator first_neighbor;
    std::vector<Node*>::const_iterator last_neighbor;
    int value;
    bool deleted;
};
```

Concatenate the adjacency lists and put them in a single `std::vector<Node*>` to lower the overhead of memory management. I'm using soft deletes so update speed is not important.

Sort pointers to the nodes by value into another `std::vector<Node*>` with a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Mark all nodes as not deleted.

Iterate through the nodes in sorted order. If the node under consideration has been deleted, go to the next one. Otherwise, mark it deleted and iterate through its neighbors and mark them deleted.

If your nodes are stored contiguously in memory, then you can omit `last_neighbor` at the cost of an extra sentinel node at the end of the structure, because `last_neighbor` of a node is `first_neighbor` of the succeeding node.

Comment: This is also a nice approach, the problem (I have to admit I omitted this in the question) is that I somethimes want to change the value of certain nodes within the deletion without having to re-sort the list. This is probably easier when storing all nodes into a map.

Comment: I was sort of wondering about that, since the attractiveness of each node to the standard greedy algorithm depends on how many of its neighbors are left. If the values can only increase, I'd use a one-level monotone priority queue (basically a vector of intrusive doubly-linked lists). Otherwise, I'd use an intrusive priority queue. Unfortunately, the STL is basically incapable of providing intrusive data structures (though you might look at Boost.Intrusive).

Comment: Thank you, I will certainly do that.

Comment: If you implement a priority queue-like design the way I explained in my answer, then the nice thing is that almost anything you can imagine will be possible in O(1) (average case), including changing priorities.